# Reset summation decimal value every time the rounding is greater than or equal to 0.01 with over partition by

Tags: sql-server, teradata, window-functions, data-partitioning, partition-by

I would like to help myself, I have a table with 4 columns, (Id, Grp, Amount, SumMonto).
The Amount column is money type and handles 4 decimal places. so values ​​of 0.0001 are stored.
I want to add the Cumulative Amount column and every time its value is equal to or greater than 0.01 (rounded value) it is recorded in the row that
corresponds to the accumulated sum and for those that are less than 0.01, zero must be registered

This is my example code (**sql v17.9**)

```
if object_id('tempdb..#example') is not null   
    drop table #example
 
CREATE TABLE #example (
Id INTEGER identity(1,1),
Grp  INTEGER NULL,
DateT VARCHar(8),
Amount money NULL
);


INSERT INTO #example VALUES (1,'20210101',0.0037);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (1,'20210102',0.0037);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (1,'20210103',0.0037);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (1,'20210104',0.0037);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (1,'20210105',0.0037);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (1,'20210106',0.0037);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (1,'20210107',0.0037);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (1,'20210108',0.0012);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (1,'20210109',0.0012);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (2,'20210101',0.0012);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (2,'20210102',0.0012);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (2,'20210103',0.0012);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (2,'20210104',0.0012);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (2,'20210105',0.0012);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (2,'20210106',0.0100);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (2,'20210107',0.0018);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (2,'20210108',0.0018);
INSERT INTO #example VALUES (2,'20210109',0.0548);
```

I have made the accumulation with sum (Amount) but it only accumulates the value and I don't know how to reset the accumulation when it is greater than or equal to 0.01 and that
it registers the zero in the row that does not accumulate the penny

this my code and the output (**I have used case instructions but I couldn't so I copy the base instruction**)

```
select  Id,Grp,DateT,Amount ,
              sum(Amount) OVER
                      (
                             PARTITION BY Grp
                             ORDER BY DateT --ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                      ) Accumulated
       from #example
   
   
Id          Grp         DateT                 Amount                Accumulated
----------- ----------- --------------------- ------------------- ---------------------
1           1           20210101           0.0037                0.0037
2           1           20210102           0.0037                0.0074
3           1           20210103           0.0037                0.0111
4           1           20210104           0.0037                0.0148
5           1           20210105           0.0037                0.0185
6           1           20210106           0.0037                0.0222
7           1           20210107           0.0037                0.0259
8           1           20210108           0.0012                0.0126
9           1           20210109           0.0012                0.0138
10          2           20210101           0.0012                0.0012
11          2           20210102           0.0012                0.0024
12          2           20210103           0.0012                0.0036
13          2           20210104           0.0012                0.0048
14          2           20210105           0.0012                0.0060
15          2           20210106           0.0100                0.0160
16          2           20210107           0.0018                0.0178
17          2           20210108           0.0018                0.0196
18          2           20210109           0.0548                0.0744
```

In the following table, I indicate how the values ​​should come out when accumulating to 0.01 and resetting the value to zero when it is not 0.01.

```
Id          Grp         DateT                 Amount                Accumulated
----------- ----------- --------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
1           1           20210101           0.0037                   0.0000
2           1           20210102           0.0037                   0.0000
3           1           20210103           0.0037                   0.0100
4           1           20210104           0.0037                   0.0000
5           1           20210105           0.0037                   0.0000
6           1           20210106           0.0037                   0.0100
7           1           20210107           0.0037                   0.0000
8           1           20210108           0.0012                   0.0000
9           1           20210109           0.0012                   0.0000
10          2           20210101           0.0012                   0.0000
11          2           20210102           0.0012                   0.0000
12          2           20210103           0.0012                   0.0000
13          2           20210104           0.0012                   0.0000
14          2           20210105           0.0012                   0.0100
15          2           20210106           0.0100                   0.0100
16          2           20210107           0.0018                   0.0000
17          2           20210108           0.0018                   0.0000
18          2           20210109           0.0548                   0.0600
```

This routine would apply to an average of 7 million records or more for the purpose of finding an optimal option.
thank you very much any recommendation

Comment: SQL Server or Teradata?  Your code looks like SQL Server.

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to) cumulative sum, you can generate cumulative adjustment (cumulative sum truncated to two decimal places). Then make this query a CTE or subquery and use LAG to subtract prior adjustment from current adjustment to see "where the penny goes".

Answer (score 1):

You can have the difference with this expression :

```
      FLOOR(100*(sum(Amount) OVER
              (
                     PARTITION BY Grp
                     ORDER BY DateT
              ))) / 100.0 Accumulated2
```

Comment: SQLpro.
thanks @SQLpro  for the answer but the problem is that I cannot subtract the sum every time a cumulative sum exceeds 0.01.
The objective is that when it does not exceed 0.01, 0 is recorded, and when it is greater than or equal to 0.01, this value or the accumulated value is recorded.

Comment: Add another windowed function using LAG to detect when this value is changing from the previous and make it NULL when no changes has been detected. Something like CASE WHEN LAG(...) ... = value THEN value ELSE 0 END